# How to remove unwanted encoding symbols in json

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have json on my page coming from the string property of the model:

```
   var myJson = '[{\"A\":1,\"B\":10,\"C\":\"214.53599548339844\",\"D\":\"72.52798461914062\"},
    {\"A\":1,\"B\":11,\"C\":\"214.53599548339844\",\"D\":\"72.52798461914062\"}]'
```

I want to process that json via javascript on the page

I am doing `$.parseJSON(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myJason)));` but json still contain `\"` symbol. If i do `$.parseJSON(@Html.Raw(Json.Decode(myJason)));` it is just producing an `$.parseJSON(System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonArray);` How can I fix that?

Comment: well your problem is that your JSON is not JSON, so fix that and you are good to go. That is whereever the JSON is produced there's an error that escapes the qoutation marks and they should be escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your JSON and **.stringify()** it. Then use the **.replace()** method and replace all occurrences of ("\").

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(myJson);
var myNewString = myString.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: on `myString.replace("\", "");`saying unterminated constant

Comment: yes, you can check edited answer now. I got it working for me.

Comment: it's missing a quotation mark. it should be `myString.replace("\"","")`. That is two quotatio marks right after the backslash

Comment: @RuneFS  two quotatio marks right after the backslash will only solve the problem of unterminated constant, but it wont give expected result.

Comment: Well it was an comment to a) your original code and b) the comment reg. the unterminated string.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways 
1 from where you get the JSON asked them to send you as url encoded format. at your end you need to decode url and you will get the Perfect JSON.

Other wise do the laborious replace method for each and every special charecter with respective char.

like above example you need to use replace("\","");

Answer (score 1):

There is no JSON parser that will be able to deal with a JSON string that isn't properly formatted in the first place.

so you need to make sure that your theModel is formatted appropriately and according [JSON.org](http://json.org/) standards.

Like 
Koushik say you can use String operation